# In MacVim, I want to make it so the cursor does not blink

Tags: vimrc, macvim

In my vimrc file, I have the two lines

```
let &t_SI="\033[6 q" " start insert mode (steady bar, xterm)
let &t_EI="\033[2 q" " end insert mode
```

When I am in the terminal, the box does not blink(the normal mode cursor box); however, in MacVim these lines do not seem to do anything. I changed 6 to I think 5 and nothing changed. I was wondering if anyone else has run into this problem and how I can fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: See `:help 'guicursor'`.

Comment: Thank you that helped when I performed, ```set guicursor=a:blinkon0```

Comment: @romainl or user42457 that sounds like an answer to me. As romainl alludes to, the GUI has its own cursor mechanism that is completely independent from any terminal.